# How to deal with changing "number" of nodes in Adjacency Matrix

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I am new to algebraic graph theory and my question may be naive: Adjacency matrix (AM) captures well the connection space between nodes of a graph - connections can easily come and go, where new ones could be formed and existing ones easily removed within the AM. But what about vertices (nodes) coming and going (new nodes added to the graph or removed)? Is there a good theoretical treatment of this level of variation without needing to adjust the dimension of the AM?

Comment: I don't understand, you already know the dimension of the adjacency matrix equals the number of nodes, so why would you ask if you can change the number of nodes but not the dimension? For practical purposes, if you can anticipate a maximum number of nodes, you can set that to be the dimension, then just not use any unused nodes.

Comment: Thank you runway44. This is a graph with changing number of vertices: At time=t1 the number of nodes in the graph is n1, at time=t2 it the number of nodes in the graph is n2.  What you are suggesting could work: plan for future/max number of nodes and fix the dim of the adjacency matrix based on an anticipated maximum. I am wondering if there could be a different conceptual construct other than the adjacency matrix, that could encode a variable number of nodes the way adjacency matrix captures the variability of the number of edges.

Comment: *Technically*, it's not "a" graph with a changing number of vertices, it's a different graph at different times. But I get what you mean.

Comment: That's actually helpful insight runway44: indeed it's a different graph at different times - so perhaps I should be looking for conceptual constructs/representations that generalize to variability over the "space of graphs" vs parameter space of an individual graph. That brings up the next question: where does the discussion of  "space" of graphs {G} belong to? Topology?